# Mailjet for loop with index

Tags: mailjet

I understand that Mailjet can do: https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-templating-samples/tree/master/tutorials/digest

I wonder if there's a way to do something like `for in 1:5`.

Comment: I think at this point, Mailjet won't be able to do this, for anyone whom might be interested in the answer,